# accuracy of time series forcasting in percentage

Tags: time-series, validation

I am using a multiplicative time series model for forecasting future values, I have trend and seasonal patterns in my model. Can someone suggest me a way by which I can check the accuracy of my model? How can I know as to my forecast is what percent accurate?